# Kill and restart ngrok within a shell script

Tags: shell, sh, ngrok

I need to kill and restart my `ngrok` server every 24 hours, so I thought about using a cronjob to run a shell script. The issue I am facing is that when I restart `ngrok` within the shell script, it starts it within that given shell session.

How can I go about starting `ngrok` in a different session, so that I can continue to do other checks within the same script?

The code I have so far:

```
# grabs the PID for the current running ngrok
ngrok_pid=$(pgrep ngrok)
echo "Current ngrok PID = ${ngrok_pid}"

# kills ngrok
kill_ngrok_pid=$(kill -9 $ngrok_pid)

# get exit status code for last command
check=$?

# check if the exit status returned success
if [ $check -eq 0 ]; then
    # re-start ngrok
    $(./ngrok http 5000 &)
    # do more checks below...
else
    echo "NO ngrok PID found"
fi
```

Comment: What about launching ngrok within a GNU Screen detached session?  `screen -d -m ngrok http 5000`. Then you can just attach to the screen session to see ngrok's stdout. Also look in to Screen's `-h` option.

Comment: I can't see that `$(./ngrok http 5000 &)` is adding any advantage. I would expect `./ngrok http 5000 &` to allow the script to continue and do other things (If you need `screen` to capture output, or allow using an internal (to ngrok) command line), then I think `screen` is the only way to go. Good luck.

Comment: The other command substitution seems similarly useless. `kill -9` does not print anything, so capturing its output in a variable does nothing useful. Nothing seems to try to use that variable subsequently anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I am at all able to guess what you are trying to ask, run the new command in a subprocess. You are already doing that, albeit clumsily.

```
#!/bin/sh

ngrok_pid=$(pgrep ngrok)
echo "$0: Current ngrok PID = ${ngrok_pid}" >&2

if [ "$ngrok_pid" ] && kill -9 $ngrok_pid
then
    ( ./ngrok http 5000 & )
    # do more checks below...
else
    echo "$0: NO ngrok PID found" >&2
fi
```

This avoids [testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern) and the superfluous command substitution. `if [ "$ngrok_pid" ] &&` avoids trying to run `kill` if there is no PID. Finally we take care to include the name of the script in its diagnotic messages, and printing them to standard error `>&2` instead of standard output.

A better solution altogether might be to run `ngrok` as a service, and merely using `cron` to tell the service to restart; but how exactly to do that is system-dependent. Fortunately, [the documentation has instructions for multiple popular architectures.](https://ngrok.com/docs/agent/#background-service) Then, all you need in your `cron` job is

```
ngrok service restart
```

The original service should be launched at reboot or etc with something like

```
ngrok service install --config /etc/ngrok.yml
```

but I defer to the `ngrok` manual for details.